# Does multipart/form-data endpoint create temporary file on server

Tags: java, file-upload, jersey, jax-rs, multipartform-data

I have a REST endpoint that accepts a multipart/form-data as payload.

The file is then parsed on the server with a CSVParser (from apache commons).

Will the file be automatically created in some temporary directory, hence requiring cleaning up?

Or does the endpoint parse the file directly in memory without the need to save it on the physical disk first?

Comment: Post answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610221/file-upload-using-rest-service

Comment: @piy26 the answer suggested 2 possibilities, I'm hoping to get a definitive answer.

Comment: Yes it does create a temporary file.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Does the jersey framework clean it up for you then? If not how should we handle the clean up? The server is linux.

Answer (score 1):

The uploaded file probably kept into the default temp directory. to get the folder you can use the  `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")`. Or It may store the file into the local server's temp directory if server has.

Comment: I assume that in either case, the temp dir will have a size limit, or get auto clean up by the OS/server app, so we don't have to clean it manually?

Comment: In Windows No, there's nothing turned on by default in Windows that will automatically delete temp files. Not on shutdown, not on reboot, not ever. but server may have cleanups...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the server code?  It all depends on the implementation on the server side.  Whether it's CXF, Jersey or some other implementation, the end goal of a form multipart is typically an InputStream of some sort.  If your parser takes an input stream, it is rarely necessary to store the uploaded file in a temp directory.

Short answer, unless the code specifically writes out the input stream into a temp file somewhere, you do not need to clean up other than properly closing the input stream.

Comment: Yes the parser reads the InputStream from the form data directly: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/archives/1.5/apidocs/index.html. So I'd need to close the input stream at the end of the REST function? I'm using Jersey, the endpoint looks something like snippet 3 in https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/ (without the `writeToFile`)

Comment: If you're not writing to file, then no, you don't need to do any cleanup other than closing the inputstream

Comment: Does the jersey framework close the InputStream for you? The code snippets I have seen doesn't close the InputStream.